# Outdated Amazon_core after composer update (Magento 2.2.4)

Tags: magento2, composer, amazon-payment

I am getting this error:

```
Amazon_Core db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.0.12, currently installed - 2.0.4
```

and

```
Amazon_Core db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.12, currently installed - 2.0.4
```

I have not been able to find any information on this issue, or a packagist repo that looks like the right choice for Amazon_Core.  I also have not found anything in my composer.json that relates to Amazon_Core.

Comment: I just experienced this when upgrading to Magento 2.2.6 from .2.2.4. I'm not sure the proper method to fix this but  I simply removed all the values throwing the error from the setup_module table and running the Magento setup:upgrade command. So if anyone else has this issue, that is what my fix was.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had removed the composer package `msp/owlcarousel2` which also included an `msp/common`.  I had assumed these were both part of the `msp/owlcarousel2` package, so I removed them from the magento modules and in composer, as I no longer needed the package for our project. I then ran composer update and checked out the site which gave me the error described in the question above.

When I re-installed the `msp/owlcarousel2` package and then enabled the `MSP_Common` module in magento, the error cleared up.  Sounds like I might be a slave to that install until I can figure out how to properly remove it.

Answer (score 0):

It is what is says.  The Amazon_Core referenced as an older version in the code base from the version installed.  Disable and remove, and then reinstall.
In my case, searching for "Amazon_Core" in all magento root dir:

```
$ egrep -ir Amazon_Core .
```

Resulted in a lot of instances where it is referenced, used, and logged.  Also, I got a recommendation from the:
"vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module/docs/installation.rst:*

Enable the extension:

```
   `php bin/magento module:enable Amazon_Core Amazon_Login Amazon_Payment`
```

Disable the extension:

```
   `php bin/magento module:disable Amazon_Core Amazon_Login Amazon_Payment`
```

I disabled them, and the error disappeared.  I think if you want to use these extensions, you need to update the packages first.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Amazon payments you can remove via composer. Edit composer.json in web root

```
"require": {
        [...]
    },
    "replace": {
        "amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-php": "*",
        "amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module": "*",
        "amzn/login-with-amazon-module": "*",
        "amzn/amazon-pay-module": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        [...]
```

Run `composer install`

This is safer than module enable / disable command